# How to refer to a specific field in a row while querying in CSV file

Tags: python, file, csv, field, rows

```
  filename = selectedCompany + "/" + "1" + ".txt"  # define filename to save file with
        for row in csv_file:
            if selectedCompany == row[1]:
                count +=1
                if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(filename)):
                    try:
                        os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(filename))
                    except OSError as exc:  # Guard against race condition
                        if exc.errno != errno.EEXIST:
                            raise
        totalCnt=0
        print listOfCompanies #to debug
        print selectedCompany #to debug
        while totalCnt < len(csv_file): # as long as total count is lesser than length of csv file
            totalCnt+=1        # add total count of 1
            for row in csv_file:
                if selectedCompany == row[:][1]: # if selected company equals to the company in csv file
                    with open(filename, "w") as output:  # save the .txt file
                        output.write(str(csv_file[totalCnt])) # save the contents of the csv file
                else:
                    totalCnt+=1  # add total count of 1
```

Hi all, I'm using python to read data from a csv file and export them as individual .txt files. 
My question is how do I refer to a specific field in a specific row?

For example my data set in a csv file is as follows

name gender age
  john   m     15
  mary   f     13
  sam    m     12

Upon the user's input of the name (i.e sam), I would like to be able to export the whole row of data (i.e "sam , m , 12" ) as data and export it as a .txt file.

If i want to pin point to sam's gender, for example, how do I go about doing it?
And furthermore, how do I use the for loop properly to ensure that I can export all the necessary .txt files I want?

I've tried searching around, however my case is a logic error and it's really tough to troubleshoot.

Would really appreciate any help.

Edit:

Error message after using panda module:

```
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1797, in 
    __getitem__
    return self._getitem_column(key)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1804, in _ 
   getitem_column
    return self._get_item_cache(key)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1084, in 
    _get_item_cache
    values = self._data.get(item)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 2851, 
    in get
    loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\index.py", line 1572, in 
    get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(_values_from_object(key))
     File "pandas\index.pyx", line 134, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc 
    (pandas\index.c:3824)
     File "pandas\index.pyx", line 154, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc 
    (pandas\index.c:3704)
     File "pandas\hashtable.pyx", line 686, in p 
    pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:12280)
      File "pandas\hashtable.pyx", line 694, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:12231)
KeyError: False
```

Comment: I would look into the standard library's [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module. It provides a convenient `reader()` object comprised of a list of lists which you can subscript (i.e. index by col).

Comment: Or even `DictReader` that uses the col headers as dictionary keys

Comment: Hi Sarah, please check my answer and ask me what do you need more I will try to help.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would think about Pandas package - with that package your task could be very simple e.g.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("CSVFILE.csv", sep=',') # if you have your csv with headers it will create dataframe with names name | gender | age
desiredoutput = data[data.name == USERINPUT] #USERINPUT is e.g. sam (it us up to you how you gain it.. e.g. via input() command)
```

Your output is also comma separated values ((i.e "sam , m , 12" ))
so you can save it easily to csv containig only one line which you select by user input.

```
desiredoutput.to_csv("NAMEYOUCHOOSE.csv", sep = ",", index=False, header=False)
```

Comment: Hi Petr

I've obtained several error messages which I've no idea what they mean. Any advice?

Comment: Can you share those messages? Maybe you do not have installed pandas package (e.g. via pip install pandas)

Comment: They are in my original post.

Comment: Can you show us current version of that code? I do not see any pandas usage within you code. Have you try to run my code snippet?